# Getting extent of a point cloud using laspy

Tags: pdal, laspy

As part of a geo-indexing script, I'd like to add in support for numerous .laz files we have sitting around on our SAN.  The only intent of the handler is to grab the filename/path, the SRS, and the extent of the point cloud file.  I do not need to do any processing or analysis on the dots.

So I'm able to do

```
from laspy.file import File

my_file = File("path/to/file.laz", mode='r')
```

and it loads the files without error.  I can call the `File.header` property, but have no idea how to "get into" it to extract values or calculate the min/max X/Y.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `min` and `max` property of `header`.

```py
from laspy.file import File

f = File("path/to/file.laz", mode='r')
h = f.header

# h.min: [min_x, min_y, min_z] - h.max: [max_x, max_y, max_z]
extent = [*h.min, *h.max] # extent: [min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z]
```

Comment: Thanks Kadir; is there a way for me to discern the spatial reference from the header?  Or just dump all the header contents as a dict and look through them?  I was able to grab the min/max as you showed but it was just line and sample, not coordinate information.

Comment: I've just looked at laspy docs. It says "srs is not implemented". So, you should probably dump the header contents or use `liblas`.

Comment: Great. How do I dump the header contents? That was part of the question alluded to in my original question on how to get into the header to examine all the values.

Comment: Please check these posts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203395/29431 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80762/29431

Comment: Use PDAL to get your SRS info.

Comment: @HowardButler *how* do I use PDAL to get my SRS info?

Answer (score 2):

As @HowardButler says, you can also use PDAL for this. The documentation is a little hard to find, but you can do it without any need to call subprocess.

First, we need to load the file as a PDAL pipeline:

```py
import pdal
from shapely.geometry import shape, box
from shapely.ops import transform
from pyproj import Transformer
import fiona

filename = "/path/to/las"
pipeline = pdal.Reader.las(filename=data, count=1).pipeline()
pipeline.execute()
```

`count=1` here makes PDAL load only a single datapoint for speed. I would assume it's possible that some LAS files don't contain this metadata in the header and you need to iterate over all points to find the min/max. For my test dataset it doesn't make a difference, but to be safe, omit `count`.

Then you can access the `metadata` property to load the info needed (all returned as dictionaries). I'd recommend exploring the dictionary keys here to figure out what info you need, but for example:

```py
# Get the metadata
meta = pipeline.metadata['metadata']

# Bounds
minx = meta['readers.las']['minx']
miny = meta['readers.las']['miny']
maxx = meta['readers.las']['maxx']
maxy = meta['readers.las']['maxy']
las_bbox = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

import pyproj
las_crs = pyproj.crs.CRS(meta['readers.las']['srs']['proj4'])
```

From here you can do whatever you need - for example, load an arbitrary shapefile and check if any feature intersects the LAS file:

```py
shapefile_path = "/path/to/shapefile"

with fiona.open(shapefile_path, "r") as shapefile:

    project = Transformer.from_crs(shapefile.crs, las_crs, always_xy=True).transform

    for i, feature in enumerate(shapefile):
        geometry = feature["geometry"]
        feature_bounds = transform(project, shape(geometry))
        print(feature_bounds.within(las_bbox))
```